# How to edit data size on the cache file using Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, caching, size

STEPS TO REPRODUCE THE PROBLEM:

- **Step 1:** Let´s say you have cleaned up your cache history on your browser (firefox).
- **Step 2:** You type www.stackoverflow.com on your browser to could get some new data on your cache folder.
- **Step 3:** you type on your browser "cache:about"
- **Step 4:** you click on "Disk cache device/List cache entries"
- **Step 5:** I search for some ".png" file that has been downloaded to my cache folder. And taking notice that the data size is actually 16425bytes.
- **Step 6:** Copy the path where the image has been stored on your computer.
- **Step 7:** I take a fast look how the image looks like by clicking on this link before I continue with the problematic issue.
- **Step 8:** Checking image
- **Step 9:** Start/run/ and pasting the path we have copied recently, where the image has been stored on your system.
- **Step 10:** Here is the image! But we have to type manually ".png"
- **Step 11:** I take a look how it looks like:
- **Step 12:** I edit the image I want to change the size of the file and have another size than the real one that the browser cached. So I make the image smaller and save it.
- **Step 13:** I check so the size of the file have really changed.
  before was 17kb now 3kb.
- **Step 14:** I remove the ".png" text i added to the file name so the browser can read it
- **Step 15:** Now I press reload on my browser and the file don´t gets readed!

EXPECTED RESULT:
 - On the example to make it simple to understand I used a ".png" but you don´t get the same result. On my real issue amb trying to make the cache read a FLASH .swf file that I hade change it activly the original data size.. 
Any ideas? links? I can´t find info on internet about how to say to the browser to read again the file that has been downloaded, even if the size has changed!!

Comment: I think I know what you mean. In Firefox you have to edit a SQLite cache database file, so you need a special software to do this properly where you change the size attribute of the cached entry in the SQLite file and possibly the embedded file data itself. Chrome too probably. I think the image and other cached files are actually embedded within the SQLite file itself so you cannot edit an image file that's in a folder but have to edit the cache file directly like you would do in database blobs, using a special database file editor.

Comment: This starts to sound great, what do you think about going under the cache folder and trying to edit the "_CACHE_001_" file

(In my case under the following path: C:\Documents and Settings\jan\Lokala inställningar\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\86dr4ufx.default\Cache\)

Example of some content inside the file:
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Content-Type: image/png
Date: Sun, 10 Feb 2013 02:02:17 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 15 Feb 2012 18:40:19 GMT
Server: ECAcc (arn/4699)
X-Cache: HIT
Content-Length: 1059

Comment: I tryied to modify the 1059 value, but the thinks went worse.

Comment: you have to use an editor to do it. You cannot use Notepad. if you resave it using Notepad it will corrupt the entire file and invalidate the entire cache file to be unrecognizable by browser. I wanted to try this actually one time just for fun but never did. Maybe something like this would help? http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/ or http://www.razorsql.com/download_win.html

Comment: the reason why this is, is that Notepad does not recognize special machine code in SQLITE files (just like when you try to open .exe file in Notepad). You know those funny characters? It means "undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined", etc. If you resave it in Notepad, all those undefined's are garbage and do not reconstruct into a valid SQLITE file. Another example - open an exe in Notepad, save it, and you do NOT get a valid exe. Same with cache files. With Cache files, MAYBE one of those SQLITE editors would work.

Comment: Ok, Nice I have download it and install it, Any idea where to find more info about the workflow of this software? I couldnt find nothing by looking on the help menu of the program, or on the same sourceforge page. Then I checked on google and youtube without luck. Where did you hear about SQLite for the first time? maybe there I can find how to use it?

Comment: I heard about SQLITE just in general. It's used a lot in software.  SQLITE is like key value system of database basically except it is lightweight and put into a file to operate like mimicking a database within regular non-web-app software. Try to open your CACHE file with the SQLITE editing software. Look for the size attribute. Try to change it. Export the new file replacing the old one, and see if that works.

Comment: Yeah, I get what you mean. I gonna try my best to open the cache file and change the size value, and then save it back.. lets check

Comment: mmm.. no men.. I think the database dont have som much to do with the cache file that is created by the firefox. The program is asking me for a database file all the time.. I dont see the conection about a database and the cache file created.. mmm... any other possibility?

Comment: So opening _CACHE_001_ with the sqlite editor doesnt work?

Comment: hmm i checked it is not sqlite file that one - try Hex editor instead

Comment: Ouch.. no.. am googling after some software to edit cache files without luck :/

Comment: http://www.hhdsoftware.com/free-hex-editor might work to edit that particular file if you know what to edit, otherwise don't know.

Comment: Ok, I use to use the HexWin, so don´t worry.. but not so much there aswell I gonna try find some answer on some other forum, then! Thanks anyway! =D

Answer (score 1):

The point is that client will never check the server again if it is cached, until (and if) the cache has expired for that element. Set a max age on the HTTP header to 10 minutes say, for client to redownload it if it has been more than 10 mins since last downloaded. You cannot update just because size changed. Unless you have a JS or ajax or something that will update the client cache based on some result that is retrieved when the client checks the server to see if there was a recent change, other that it is impossible.

So if you have to have it, you will have to keep track on the server if something changes, based on existing data on the server. For instance, server keeps track of the initial size. If you change the image size (or suppose something in your web application changes it), the server will know that this has been changed on the server (because it will always get the current image size too on the server). So then you also need to keep track of the image size on the client when the image is downloaded, with either a cookie or with html5 localStorage.

So then the client part of your script requests the server on page load (sending the image size too that is stored in cookie or localStorage) and the server script will then compare the size of current image with the size sent by the client. If it is different it expires the client cache explicitly which means the client has to redownload the image explicitly. Otherwise it does nothing and just uses the cached image.

So basically you will need to treat your image much like you would a login cookiet(where server explicitly tracks it, expires it, sets new one, expires it, etc.) if you want this kind of functionality.

Comment: No men, thanks anyway to try!
If you active change the datasize of some "swf" file your browser has cached. And then press reload, it just gets nowhere for the moment. I hope to find some master that gets what I mean.

If initially the image has 100Kb, I cant change it with paint to diferent colors but always I have to save it to 100Kb, if its more or if its less the browser blows away.. Any other answers? Thanks

Comment: I think you have to change the database cache file blob entry to have the new size. If it works with exactly the same size then perhaps you can get away with just changing the size entry in the database file for that cached entry to match exactly the new file size. In some browsers you have to embed the image data in the database file too. You need special SQLite editing software to do this I believe.

Comment: Give me please some name that pops up in your head of some of this SQLite editing software

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same problem, finally got a work around, thanks to this thread.

this is for firefox only.
goto about:config
edit the variable "browser.cache.check_doc_frequency" (default 3) to 2
(http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.cache.check_doc_frequency)

edit the file in the cache directory. (doesn't matter if the new size is different!)
no need to change the file size entries in chache_001.

hope this helps you.

Edit: just make sure you keep the file size less than the original one for swf files.

Reason: I don't really know, but when I tried editing a swf for an online game, the game could no longer load with the new cache file (like firefox reserves x memory bytes for the thing, x was specified by the server .. but the file is larger than x bytes, so the whole file will not be loaded, and the flash movie wont load).

I edited some of the images in the swf to blank images of the same size, recompiled and recompressed to get a filesize lower than that of the original swf, and it worked!